# How do European PhD interviews work when a candidate is not local?

Tags: phd, interview

How do European PhD interviews work when a candidate is not local? Are virtual interviews common?

Edit: In particular, I am interested in interviewing for a German CS position when I am in Slovenia.

Comment: So can you explain your reasons for not asking them?

Comment: it would be a side question i don't want the formal process to be disturbed

Comment: You might want to write this reason (which I do not understand) into your question and explain how this would disturb the process.

Comment: i asked in general here to compare, they have their policy they would tell me to check their policy if i would ask them btw.

Comment: Then check their policy.

Comment: i want to know how it is usually done to compare their process with other universities

Comment: @cag51 i don't like the way you edit questions, it's my question not yours, and what you wrote is NOT what i am looking for to know

Comment: You may want to check out our [tour](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tour) -- editing unclear questions is very much encouraged here. If 
 you don't think my edit did you justice, you can [edit](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/139762/edit) it yourself. But, please note that unclear questions may be closed and deleted -- you may want to check our [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help) to review what is allowed and disallowed here.

Comment: In particular, we do not allow rude or abusive comments; that can lead to a suspension. Your comment to me probably isn't over the line, but I have deleted your response to Heutl above.

Answer (score 3):

Interviews through teleconferencing (e.g. Skype) are pretty common if it is not feasible to invite all shortlisted candidates for an in person interview.

However, since we are talking about Slovenia to Germany, it is very well possible they would would invite you to come over if they wanted to interview you. In such a situation it would be standard practice to reimburse your travel costs.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too wide.

But in general, if you have a particular university in mind you should check their website, else you can start your search for a field and title in particular by looking at universities that provide PHD's (there can be national databases about the registered PHDs and universities in the national department of education or equivalent of the country), and then go into their sites to see their requirements and applications processes.

But first, you need to figure out if you want a particular country or a particular program, and why.

Comment: Even with your edit, the core of this advice stands. Contact the university and ask. Even within a university, the process will be different for different phd positions depending on subject, funding, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I once had an interview for a PhD position online and we used Skype. I think it depends entirely on the university and the department. My tip would be to check with the department that you're interested in. They might also do a phone/video call first, and then invite you for an in-house meeting depending on how well the call went.

Comment: By the comments, it seems the questioner knows already about their university but is interested in a general statistics.